# mod_rewrite rule is not working

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I've used mod_rewrite rules a lot over the years, which is all the more reason for me not understanding why this will not work:

```
RewriteRule ^cottage/house/(.*)/(.*)$ /cottage/house/$1?query=$2 [L]
```

I am using it alongside the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This code should be making a URL of format `/cottage/house/housename/about` go to `/cottage/house/housename?query=about`... Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly is the rule (that does not work) placed in the file above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out the issue - Wordpress has it's own way of dealing with `mod_rewrite`.

The code below rewrites the URL internally in a way that Wordpress understands:

```
function ong_custom_house_pages() 
{
    function add_query_vars($houseVars) 
    {
        $houseVars[] = "current_house_page"; 
        return $houseVars;
    }
    add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
    add_rewrite_rule("^houses/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?",'index.php?
    houses=$matches[1]&current_house_page=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init','ong_custom_house_pages');
```

Hope this helps anyone having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

When used just on its own, the rule works quite well.

The problem is that the `[L]` in the rule only means that no more rules from this rule set (.htaccess file) are processed in this processing step.

However, the rewritten URL `/cottage/house/housename?query=about` is handed back to the URL parsing engine. As the matching rule is causing an internal redirect, the URL will be processed by the rule set again (as a sub-request).

I guess that a real file or directory matching `/cottage/house/housename?query=about` does not exist and I also assume that this URL will not be caught by another rule. This will cause the rule `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` to match, which leads to yet another sub-request, this time on `index.php` which then will display the index page. This is why it looks like the rule seems not to work properly.

*How to solve this?*

Make sure that the first sub-request gets caught by a regular rule. The actual `RewriteRule` depends on how your overall URL structure looks like, and which other rules - that are not given in your example code - are active.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Unfortunately, I've tried to insert the code int just about every location in the `.htaccess` file, but it still does not work. Should I be using something different to `[L]` in the rule?

Comment: I have since tried modifying it to `RewriteRule ^ cottage/house/(.+)/(.+)$ cottage/house/$1?house_page=$2 [R]`, and with `[N]` instead as well, but still no luck.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer you need to make sure that the rewritten rule is somehow caught when the complete rules set is processed again (doesn't matter if via `[L]` or `[R]` by the way). What page should be displayed after the rewrite is done? I mean, does the rewritten target URL somehow exist?

Comment: It only virtually exists - the site is built using Wordpress, but my current implementation means that it needs to use variables in the URL to parse the correct data into the page. It's therefore all a rewrite of the index.php. Is there any particular way to make sure it is caught again? Is it possible to modify the rule to instruct Apache to run it again? Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: Please try to change the `[L]` in the rule from the initial question to `[NS]`. This should cause it to be skipped in a sub-request and therefore the normal Wordpress Premalink mechanism should be in effect. If this doesn't work you might want to add the information about using Wordpress to your question (also as a tag to your question), so that Wordpress experts can help you better.

Comment: I'm afraid still no luck with this. I have tried following your suggestions but it still shows a 404 error. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm very sorry, because I'm running out of ideas (and I also don't have a matching setup to play with in order to reproduce this problem). One suggestion though: maybe you could check both access log and rewrite log to see what causes the 404 because maybe it's no longer a complicated logical error.